# How can I learn more about projective geometry

Tags: projective-geometry

I am here for a simple question for which I have done some search on this site and google. Considering I was successful on my search, there is not a coherent explanation about these. I would like to learn this geometry in a very detailed way. Could I get some advice on this matter?

THanks in advance. Good day...

Comment: It was obvious that I was looking for some advice on any book which is worth looking into. I find your answer quite insulting.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are a lots of books about projective geometry. So it would be interesting to know, what applications you have (if any), and what your background is.

My personal favorite is [Richter-Geberts book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-642-17285-4), since it also includes not so popular perspectives (bracket algebra) and has a very intuitive approach. It's a gem.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this book, and it really does look quite interesting.